# Crashlytics search based on crash identifier

Tags: crashlytics

Every crash found on the crashlytics has a crash identifier associated with it.We log this in our logs to identify the crashes. But when I use this to search, i don't get any result. Does crashlytic search works for crash identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values in logs aren't currently searchable but if you log a key:value pair in Crashlytics you can search on the value.

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-keys